# What public cloud could support OpenStack in a hybrid cloud deployment?

Tags: cloud-service, virtualization, cloud-computing, openstack

I would like to have an OpenStack instance powered by a hybrid cloud.  When demand becomes extremely high, I'd like to promptly leverage the unlimited resources in the public cloud.

What public cloud provider provides great computing power for OpenStack in a hybrid cloud configuration?  I read that AWS would not provide virtualization that would perform well due to emulation differences.  I'll use KVM and Linux for the private cloud.  This OpenStack deployment will not support Windows instances.